# Static website authentication to firebase backend

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, forms-authentication

Let's say I own a fully static website on https://example.com/. Just HTML, CSS and client side JS files.

Next I wanted to implement a basic commenting system allowing authenticated guests to leave comments. My plan is to use a POST form on the site and implement the commenting backend on Firebase with a Firestore database.

Authentication wise, I suppose it needs to deal with two scenarios:

- Client authentication. The site itself needs to be authenticated by the firebase backend so that only POST requests originated from the site will be accepted. What should I do? There must be no shared secret between the site and firebase because the site is static and everything in there can be accessed by visitors. Perhaps there is some kind of host based auth? Appreciated if you can point me in the right direction.
- User authentication. Guests need to be authenticated before they can post comments; Use OAuth should be fine provided the backend can deal with Facebook, Github etc.